# How do I load weights for embedding layers after increasing the vocabulary size in TensorFlow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, embedding

I am trying to use

```
model.save_weights('weights_file')
```

and

```
model.load_weights('weights_file')
```

to save a keras model with embeddings. The issue is that when I bring in new data to train on, my vocabulary for the embeddings has increased. So when I load weights I later get an error in model.fit():

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_20464\1213623340.py", line 125, in train_step
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 639, in apply_gradients
        self._create_all_weights(var_list)
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 825, in _create_all_weights
        self._create_slots(var_list)
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\adamax.py", line 100, in _create_slots
        self.add_slot(var, 'm')  # Create slots for the first moments.
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 918, in add_slot
        self._restore_slot_variable(
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 1342, in _restore_slot_variable
        checkpoint_position.restore(slot_variable)

    ValueError: Shapes (31, 5) and (15, 5) are incompatible
```

Because the embeddings were initialized with shape (31, 5), but I then load the previous weights of shape (15, 5) into them.

How do I handle this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Load the embeddings separately and perform the conversion logic in your application. You can't do this as a part of loading. It really depends on how the two embeddings are related to perform conversion logic

Comment: @thushv89 Is it bad practice to just make the input dimension significantly larger than needed? So the size doesn’t change as I train in new samples?